# SvelteKit build (w/ adapter-node) 404 on newly created static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

*Using `@sveltejs/adapter-node: 1.0.0-next.61` and `@sveltejs/kit: ^1.0.0-next.225`*

The following issue occurs only on the build version of the app, and not on the dev server, on which it doesn't occur.

When uploading a new file, my app keeps returning 404 regarding those newly created files as though the app is blind to those. Interestingly enough, said images are found when restarting the server.

The creation request succeeds: [image: POST REQUEST 200]

The file is correctly created on the filesystem and should be loaded by the page as seen in the json response which lists all files to be loaded on the page: [image: file exists]

However, when attempting to fetch the file, the server responds with a 404 although the path to it is correct: [image: 404]

Comment: Very same problem. Looks crazy! :0

Comment: I am going crazy over this! Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @MitjaKukovec Sadly not; i worked around this by serving the `static/` folder via nginx tho

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found two solutions but both are just workarounds to this very annoying problem.

- The [import](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/assets#importing) way: that's quite tricky to configure it properly (read also [this](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html)) and, overall, it becomes a pain if you need to import dynamic paths (with variables inside the import path) as it was in my case.
- The `CDN` way: use the static folder as a CDN by pointing there the webserver with a dedicated (sub)domain. This way you can link assets with success as they are "external" resources (e.g. `https://cdn.mysite.com/file1.png`, `https://cdn.mysite.com/file2.jpg`).

Bonus: if you choose the CDN workaround, can be a good idea to set [handleFetch](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks-handlefetch) to bypass the external DNS resolution and keeping traffic internally.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by using a custom server with express to serve the static files. First run "npm run build" and add a server.js file into build path.

```
// server.js
import { handler } from './handler.js';
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

// add a route that lives separately from the SvelteKit app
app.get('/img/*', express.static('static'));

// let SvelteKit handle everything else, including serving prerendered pages and static assets
app.use(handler);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

Then run "node server.js" instead of "node index.js"

Comment: This is the best solution IMO (without serving via Nginx/Apache etc). See this GitHub thread on how to serve static files as part of SvelteKit's Vite: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/10162

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by using an api endpoint to fetch my files.
I also added some performance features.
You can check the full article here:
[my medium article](https://medium.com/@monsieurlazar/sveltekit-fetch-user-generated-files-with-api-endpoint-ccc48c76ea68)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33385972)